# Any tips for putting figure's hands into the arms?

Tags: minifigures, clone-brands, disassembly

I've recently bought some Chinese LEGO-like sets and, even though the quality might not be the same as the original, I sometimes think it's a reasonable tradeoff for the 50-75% price discount. Specially if you consider I won't really play with them; they don't need to  [resist 37.000 times](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/a/1953/20390) being assembled.

One thing that really annoys me, though, is that they always send the figures without arms and hands attached, specially the hands, which are horrible to put in the arms. They are *really* tight, require a lot of pressure and hurt my fingertips. In the photo below, those 2 Chinese figures are from different sets. I struggled to fit the one with white hands, but no matter how hard I press the black hands of the other dude, I can't fit them in.

[image: hands ok for first figure, not so good for second]

I tried so hard on the next fellow that I broke his hand, leaving it stuck in his arm:

[image: figure with broken hand]

Are there any tips for placing those hands? Either avoiding so much force or improving the grip?

Comment: The issue you are experiencing is the result of clone minifigures not going through 37000 assembly cycle you've mentioned. You get what you've paid for. And the answer is pretty simple - buy LEGO minifigures if you need desired quality.

Comment: As the minifigure is covered by patents, the manufacturer of those sets are violating the law and buying them you're supporting that.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because patent right infringement goes against the LEGO Group's Fair Play requirement.

Comment: Patent right infringement, where? Violating which law of which country?

Comment: Trademark protection exists at least in the EU: https://www.bbc.com/news/world-europe-33147827

Comment: @zovits don't worry, neither myself nor the seller live in the EU.

Comment: @maraja If you tell us your actual jurisdiction, we can probably find the relevant protection agreements.

Comment: if the fit is too tight you could use a fine grit sand paper to very slightly reduce the thickness of the shafts.

Answer (score 2):

Try putting something in the minifigure hands that would give you a bigger grip or more leverage for insertion into the arms. Something like [bar 4l](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=30374) gives you a much bigger surface and with balanced pressure on both ends of the bar, you should be able to insert pretty well.

Note that almost anything that can be inserted into a hand would work.

Comment: Thanks, I have a spear somewhere and will try!